# Can't connect Android to the web, why this code doesn't work?

Tags: android

I don't know why I can't connect anywhere with this code: (the ping returns 2)

```
public class PhoneGapProjActivity extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc;
    proc = runtime.exec("ping www.google.com -c 1");
    proc.waitFor();

    Log.d("someTag", "exitValue(): " + proc.exitValue());
    ...
}
```

the permissions are as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
```

Comment: under which tag you are defining permissions?

Comment: @Waqas: under `<application ...>here</application>` and `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7">here</uses-sdk>`

Comment: ping is not the web, and not something you should rely on having available/usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your permissions under **manifest** (as direct child). For example:

```
<manifest>
   ...
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Waqas said, the permission must be declared outside the  tag.

Besides that, there is a weird characteristic in the implementation of **ping** in android that may cause you trouble. The options must be defined before the target host, so `ping www.stackoverflow.com -c 1` will not be accepted, but `ping -c 1 www.stackoverflow.com` will.

I can't assure you that's the behaviour with all android phones, but that's the behaviour i get in the Galaxy S2 with stock build and in the Nexus S running cyanogen.

Answer (score 0):

just add the following permission in your manifest file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```